# Calculate comoving distance as a function of density parameters

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, research-level

I'm constructing a likelihood function which has parameters the density parameters found in the Friedman equation found using massive gravity action $H$:

$$H(z)^2=a + b (1 + z) + c (1 + z)^2 + d (1 + z)^3 + r (1 + z)^4$$ 
ignoring units the integral I need to evaluate for the comoving distance is

$$
\int_0^Z \frac{dz}{\sqrt{a + b (1 + z) + c (1 + z)^2 + d (1 + z)^3 + r (1 + z)^4}}
$$

I put this into Mathematica and it can't do it. If I expand it out as a Taylor series I can do it. Is there any other way to evaluate this integral as a function of the parameters and $Z$?

Comment: I don't think this form as an antiderivative.  At least Gradsteyn and Ryzhik doesn't give a form for this.

Comment: As I suspected. Then how do they do it in for example this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1613v1.pdf on page 4. I need to be able to construct a likelihood function out of this which is a function of the density parameters (a,b,c,d,r).

Comment: Note that for the much simpler case $b=c=r=0$ (flat $\Lambda$CDM) the analytical solution involves elliptic functions (which is basically defined as such integrals). You should compute it numerically.

Comment: That's useful to know thanks you. But I need to be able constrain eventually the parameter of a massive gravity model so my likelihood needs to be a function of all of the parameters.

Comment: I would start by making a function that takes in parameters and a value of $z$, computes the integral and returns the value. There are ways of speeding up the computation if this turns out to be too slow, but I would cross that bridge when you get to it.

Comment: How do you know the value of the parameters? If I did that I don't understand how I would get a function of the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean? That is the one of main points of doing the MCMC (as is described in the paper): to find the best-fit values of the parameters that fits the data.

Comment: Almost every integral, in practice, needs to be done numerically.  I'd strongly recommend that here.  This function should be very smooth and well behaved, so it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. They did not have a likelihood which was a simple function of the density parameters. I'll look into that. Thank you so much Winther.